# Control TOC metadata passed to PDF viewer TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, viewers

I am using some special characters in the names of some of my sections and these show up in the document's TOC.  The PDF looks great, just how I want.  However, when I open the PDF in my browser, the special characters are getting messed up in my browser's TOC sidebar.  (I'm using MS Edge.)  How can I pass the strings I want to see populate in the sidebar?  I would be happy to see a simple "M3" in standard characters.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,notitlepage]{article}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage[left=1.25in,right=1.25in,top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in,centering]{geometry} 
\usepackage{bm}    
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FORMAT TOC %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\Large \underline{\underline{$\,\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$Contents$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$}}\hfill\newline}   
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{1ex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\newif\iffirst\firsttrue 

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=2in,right=2in,top=1.4in,bottom=1.4in}
\large{
\tableofcontents
\restoregeometry
\newpage
\large{  
    
\section{WORKS FINE} 
 
\subsection{WORKS FINE}

\section*{\phantomsection\underline{Part I: TITLE WORKS FINE IN BROWSER}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\underline{Part I: TITLE WORKS FINE IN BROWSER}}

\section{The $\boldsymbol{\hat M^3}$ Operator and its Equation}

\subsection{Introduction}

}%%%END LARGE
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `\texorpdfstring` to declare an alternative representation for the bookmarks. Your options what you write there are a bit restricted: bookmarks can't be formatted, they don't know math typesetting. Basically you have to use what you find in unicode. Something like this can work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{WORKS FINE}
\section{The \texorpdfstring{$\boldsymbol{\hat M^3}$}{M̂³} Operator and its Equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome!!!  Thanks a lot.